# Sql to Pymongo generation using Pyparsing

Tags: python, parsing, mongodb, pymongo, pyparsing

I am using the "awesomest" parsing library in the world existing right now. Pyparsing. The problem at hand is to generate a PyMongo dictionary from a given SQL string (For select statements). The grammar def I am using is following :

```
sql_stmt = (select_key_word + ('*' | column_list).setResultsName
                 ("columns") + form_key_word + table_name_list.setResultsName
                 ("collections") + 
                 Optional(where_condition, "").setResultsName("where"))
```

Here the select_key_word, column_list etc. constructs are valid grammar defs. and using this i can parse a string like "Select * from collection_1 where (Sal = 1000 or Sal=5000) AND Car>2"
The problem i have is that, the where part is being parsed is like this :

```
[[u'where', [u'(', [u'Sal', '=', u'1000'], 'or', [u'Sal', '=', u'5000'], u')'], 'and', [u'Car', '>', u'2']]]
```

Which is fine if i want it translated into something sqlish. But a valid representation of that same in pymongo would be something like this :

```
{u'$or': [{u'$and': [{u'Sal': u'1000'}, {u'Sal': u'5000'}]}, {u'Car': {u'$gte': u'2'}}]}
```

That is where I am stuck. Can anybody give me a direction? it seems to me that setParseAction will be a way to go, but just can't figure that out

the code for the where_contidion is :

```
where_expr = Forward()
and_keyword = get_conjunction_as_grammar("and")
or_keyword = get_conjunction_as_grammar("or")
in_operation = get_operation_as_grammar("in")

column_value = get_real_number_as_grammar() | get_int_as_grammar() | \
                quotedString
binary_operator = get_bin_op_as_grammar()
col_name = get_column_name_as_grammar()

where_condn = Group(
(col_name + binary_operator + column_value) |
(col_name + in_operation + "(" + delimitedList(column_value) + ")" ) |
("(" + where_expr + ")")
)
where_expr << where_condn + ZeroOrMore((and_keyword | or_keyword) 
                                        + where_expr)

where_condition = Group(CaselessLiteral("where") + where_expr)
```

Thanks in advance. Please let me know if you need any other information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, parse actions are just the thing for this kind of project. Also, if you are trying to evaluate an expression that can have parenthetical nesting of operations of varying precedence, then operatorPrecedence is often a handy shortcut:

```
from pyparsing import *

and_keyword = CaselessKeyword("and")
or_keyword = CaselessKeyword("or")
in_operation = CaselessKeyword("in")

value = quotedString | Word(alphanums)
comparisonOp = oneOf("= != > < >= <=")
LPAR,RPAR = map(Suppress,"()")
valueList = LPAR + delimitedList(value) + RPAR
comparisonExpr = value + comparisonOp + value | value + in_operation + Group(valueList)
def makePymongoComparison(tokens):
    v1,op,v2 = tokens
    if op != 'in':
        if op != '=':
            op = {
                "!=" : "$ne",
                ">"  : "$gt",
                "<"  : "$lt",
                ">=" : "$gte",
                "<=" : "$lte",
                }[op]
            v2 = "{'%s': '%s'}" % (op, v2)
        return "{'%s': '%s'}" % (v1, v2)
    else:
        return "{'%s': {'$in': [%s]}}" % (v1, ','.join("'%s'"%v for v in v2))
comparisonExpr.setParseAction(makePymongoComparison)

def handleBinaryOp(op):
    def pa(tokens):
        return "{'$%s': %s}" % (op, ', '.join(tokens.asList()[0][::2]))
    return pa
handleAnd = handleBinaryOp("and")
handleOr  = handleBinaryOp("or")
whereOperand = comparisonExpr
where_expr = operatorPrecedence(whereOperand,
    [
    (and_keyword, 2, opAssoc.LEFT, handleAnd),
    (or_keyword, 2, opAssoc.LEFT, handleOr),
    ])

where_condition = Group(CaselessLiteral("where") + where_expr)

print where_expr.parseString("(Sal = 1000 or Sal=5000) AND Car>2")[0]
print where_expr.parseString("(Sal = 1000 or Sal=5000) AND Car in (1,2,3)")[0]
```

prints:

```
{'$and': {'$or': {'Sal': '1000'}, {'Sal': '5000'}}, {'Car': '{'$gt': '2'}'}}
{'$and': {'$or': {'Sal': '1000'}, {'Sal': '5000'}}, {'Car': {'$in': ['1','2','3']}}}
```

Still needs a few tweaks, but I hope this gets you further along.

Comment: Thank you very much! and also thank you for writing such a great library:) u r awesome.